# Rails routes custom path to controllers not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

I changed the structure of my Ruby on Rails app, I want the 'app' folder to be inside a backend folder. in config/routes.rb I have this:

```
 get '/', controller:'../backend/app/controllers/static_pages_controller#root'
```

But when I start the server it give the error :

'../backend/app/controllers/static_pages_controller#root' is not a supported controller name.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need to move the app inside `backend` folder, working against conventions will be much more work and I don't know if there is an easier way to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write full-path. You should know about **convention over configuration**, that is the major idea about Ruby on Rails.

so, 
`root 'static_pages_controller#index'`will be find.
if the backend is namespace,

```
namespace :backend, path: '/' do
  root 'static_pages_controller#index'
end
```

Comment: The point is i'm going against the convention and asking if there is a way to do it. What you said only works if I stay within the convention